# How to store "count(*)" value in a variable in NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I want to store the result of count (ex:- 5) in MySQL query to a variable, but it is storing the whole JSO string as `[{"COUNT(*)":8}]`, so How to store value `8` in my variable row?

My code in NodeJS:

```
connection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM issues',
            function(err, rows){
            var row=JSON.stringify(rows);
            console.log(row);

            });
```

Comment: use alias: `SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use sql alias:

```
connection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM issues', (err, rows) => {
    const count = rows[0].count;
    // const count = rows[0]['COUNT(*)']; // without alias
    console.log(`count: ${count}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply extract the value from the rows object by key. `rows[0]['COUNT(*)']` should work. Do that before you stringify it.

EDIT: As the comment below pointed out, `rows` is an array. Edited answer.

Comment: You forgot about `rows` is an array :)